# How to connect two anchors of the same path in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have a path in GIMP, that is missing a single segment between two anchor points. How do I connect/join them?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to connect them. Note the two overlapping circles icon next to the cursor when the correct mode is used.

[image: How to connect two anchors of a path in GIMP]

Instead of holding Ctrl down, you can also select the "Edit" mode in the "Tool Options" dockable dialog.

For more information, see [section "Edit Mode" in GIMP documentation about paths](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-path.html).